# Scrapy does not follow extracted link

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, data-extraction

Scrapy does not follow scraped link. When I call the function, which should extract details from the link scraped before, it does not work and instead it scrapes stuff from the start_urls.

```
import scrapy


class OlxSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'olx'
    start_urls = ['https://www.olx.pl/nieruchomosci/mieszkania/wynajem/wroclaw/']
    allowed_domains = ['www.olx.pl']

    def parse(self, response):

        urls = response.css('a.detailsLink::attr(href)').extract()
        for url in urls:
            url = response.urljoin(url)
            yield response.follow(url, callback=self.parse_indetail)

    def parse_indetail(self, response):
        item = {}
        item['price'] = response.xpath('//h3/text()').extract()

        yield item
```

Comment: Hi, I have a doubt in your question , is it correct to use "response.urljoin(url)", response is something which you received from start_urls, it is not a url link.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly add in **start_requests** and then iterate through:

Here is an example :

```
class Olx(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'olx'

url = 'https://www.olx.in/api/relevance/search?category=1725&facet_limit=100&location=1000001&location_facet_limit=20&.....etc...etc...'

headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36'
}

def __init__(self):
    with open('results.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
        csv_file.write('title,description,location,features,date,price\n')

def start_requests(self):
    for page in range(0, 5):
        yield scrapy.Request(url=self.url + '&page=' + str(page), headers=self.headers, callback=self.parse)

def parse(self, res):
```

Comment: Do I have to use an API of the service? Or can I just scrape it normally?

Comment: Yes, to do it how I suggest you will need to use the API - for instance if you use : https://www.olx.in/api/relevance/search?category=1720 you will be scraping vehicles, 1725 is property, and so on. But I'd recommend using the API